# Why is Data so awkward on the Enterprise?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-tng, star-trek-data

Having seen most episodes in TNG, and being an all around big fan, I am constantly surprised that Data is so awkward. Yeah I know, he's "not a human but is trying to become human". But he already has a decorated Starfleet career before coming on the enterprise. I would imagine that someone so observant would have, at some point in the twenty years prior (including fifteen years on the USS Trieste), picked up on most of the things that continue to baffle him on the Enterprise.

So why is Data still so awkward? Looking for in-universe explanations.

Comment: Wouldn't you be awkward if you were an emotionless android?

Comment: @RyanJ - I think the question is, why did his demeanour improve so dramatically in the years on the Enterprise when it hadn't done so before.

Comment: Picard and crew were also some of the finest that Starfleet had to offer. Maybe being around such excellence helped Data excel where he hadn't before?

Comment: Awkward physically? or socially?

Comment: @RyanJ There's no doubt that the Enterprise crew was the Cream of the Crop (well except Barclay, but that's another story). That doesn't explain why his social progression on the Enterprise seems uncharacteristic of a twenty year veteran.

Comment: @Catija Definitely socially. Data's physical appearance is clearly non-human, but it isn't any more awkward than dozens of non-humans that serve on the Enterprise and Starfleet in general.

Comment: Sure, I just wanted to make sure. The question didn't make it clear so I thought I'd check. My line of thought comes from thinking about people learning a new language... if you take everything literally word for word, you'll know what they're saying but you'll miss half of the nuance. Data knows the literal meanings of everything... but he's still learning the nuance.

Comment: @Catija Data didn't know the word "snoop" in the first episode, so there were some odd gaps in his knowledge (that any basic dictionary could have filled) when he first arrived, so he was missing more than just the knowledge of nuanced behavior.

Comment: @Xantec That sounds almost more like an error on the part of the writing...

Comment: @Catija Maybe, but error or not it is a fact.

Comment: As TNG progresses, Data's learning how to learn. I don't think he was this able to learn(socially) in the years prior. There are timelapse circuits, which only switch on when he is 'ready'. The dreaming in "Birthright" although initiated by accident, is an example of this timelapse.

Comment: corsiKa -who said that Data spent 15 years on the Trieste?  Star trek Chronology: The History of the Future, does NOT state that in its biography of Data.  Did First Contact, Insurrection, or Nemisis have any statement to that effect?  If not, your statement would not be based on totally canonical sources.

Comment: Because he was a poorly written and poorly acted character? Compare with The Doctor on Voyager- also a being that came into existence relatively recently, but didn't have bizarre knowledge gaps or an inexplicable lack of most emotions.

Comment: @M.A.Golding I don't remember the exact source I used, but my question stands without that - he spent those 15 years doing -something-, probably with people.

Comment: @MgSam I don't think it's fair to compare to future similar characters who all benefited from experience Brent Spiner and the writers who wrote Data's character gained. I would also question that he was poorly acted - I think his is one of the best acted characters on the show, which has always been *very* low budget to begin with!

Comment: @RyanJ if? This is Scifi.SE! Being awkward emotionless androids is kind of our thing!

Comment: @corsiKa Barclay is a superb technical diagnostician.

Comment: @PaulD.Waite Absolutely, and even though I'd imagine most people that are selected to serve on the fleet's flagship are he still seems to be a cut above the norm. Could you provide context for why you've made that particular comment?

Comment: @corsiKa: oh yeah, because you said “the Enterprise crew was the Cream of the Crop (well except Barclay, but that's another story)” nine months ago.

Comment: @PaulD.Waite Oh yeah... I wonder what I was thinking at that time... there had to be a reason!! Or maybe I was just picking on the guy hahaha... sure makes me wonder.

Comment: @MgSam The Doctor was explicitly programmed to simulate emotions and converse with patients while he worked.  He had a solid foundation to build upon; Data had almost nothing (active, at least).

Answer (score 18):

The following is pure supposition. Bear with me.

### Friends.

A big part of socialisation is having friends who're willing to spend time with you and tell you when you're not doing it right. There's no indication that Data had *any* friends on his old ship. When he comes to the Enterprise, he and Geordi [hit it off and bond almost immediately](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BNJxOc12O3c) and, despite a few run-ins with Pulaski, he is accepted as a **sentient being** by his colleagues and peers, gets invited to poker games, etc.

### Small talk

In TNG: Starship Mine, we see Data experimenting with a "[small-talk routine](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RVnvNhiM9kg)", something he's evidently been working on in order to emulate humans more effectively. It's only by being around people that he's able to actually **see what his own deficiencies are**.

### Data is really young

It's worth noting that although Data was built as an adult, in many way's he's childlike. It's not until he gets to the Enterprise that he begins to explore [his sexuality](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9ev1ec0Z0GI), to [understand humour](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=u-0Tqa-jv9U) and enters into his [first romantic relationship](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WQRkujeod6Y).

### Mentors

It's not hard to identify that both Riker and Picard have an enormous influence on Data, encouraging him to explore his own humanity in a wide variety of ways he had never considered before, focusing on art ([painting](http://media.liveauctiongroup.net/i/9646/10500194_2.jpg?v=8CE714124B67990) and [poetry](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=krD2_CN72-s)), culture ([plays](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ykBV6-7klGw) and [music](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/53835/20774)) and philosophy to better understand the humans around him.

### External influences.

A whole bunch of miscellaneous *stuff* happens to Data over the seven seasons of TNG, all of which contributes to his seeming more human, none of which happened in his prior years:

- Data [gets zapped with a funny ray](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DLIU5tC3LAs).
- Data [gets an emotion chip](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UZpTojhnKqM).
- Data [begins to dream](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=A7ga0CxQ4WU)
- Data [builds a daughter](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5RNuTvEC1H8)
- Data [loses his memory](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Thine_Own_Self_(episode))
- Data [takes command](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HKII3sFUCgs)
- Data [learns to kill](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Kivas_Fajo)

Comment: But he didn't kill.   That wouldn't be heroic.

Comment: Related to the first point about friends: when Data is given command of a ship during the Klingon civil war his first officer doesn't trust him and wants to be immediately transferred. It is very possible that that is how most of his previous crews viewed and acted toward him.

Comment: To support the third point on Data's age: chronologically Data wasn't much older than Wesley (*The Schizoid Man*). Most of that time was spent behaving as an adult (attending the Academy and serving in Starfleet) rather than growing as a person. He probably should have gone to school like Lal.

Comment: Another big external influence is that Data begins to dream while on the Enterprise.

Comment: *Well-reasoned* and *well-evidenced* supposition. +1

Comment: Other external influences: Data had parts of the ship's library written into his memory allowing him to act more human (Fistful of Datas), had multiple emotional personalities take over his neural net (The Schizoid Man, Masks).

Comment: Data also had a pet on the Enterprise, although there is no evidence that he didn't have one at his previous postings, so he might've had them earlier.

Comment: @ThePopMachine He tried to. It was only because he was beamed out at exactly the right moment that he didn't, and then he immediately lied about his attempt. (Should "learned to lie" be on the list?) As for heroism, I don't see the relevance or the justification for not being heroic. Data was killing to stop one man from continuing to kill and enslave other people. We can argue the ethics all day long, but there is a large body of people who *would* consider that heroic, even if unfortunate.

Comment: @jpmc26:   You were supposed to interpret that entire comment in quote.   As in, the writers didn't have that happen because then the heroism of Data would be put in doubt (at least for some people) and it would cause all kinds of other character development problems.   That is a pretty typical way to avoid certain big moral questions in Star Trek. Oh no, we have this big moral problem of the week.   Major Character has to decide what to do about this problem.   Oh phew!  That guy died anyways before Major Character had to make a difficult decision he/she was close to making. Quandry resolved.

Answer (score 2):

Data was 26 years old in the first season, 11 years older than Wesley, (1.733 times as old) and yet was not so humanly socially advanced as Wesley.

Obviously the writers wrote stories and scenes showing Data becoming more Human-like during his seven years during TNG, and not during his previous 26 years of activity, because scenes set before the first episode would never be seen.  But we need to explain why Data suddenly made a lot more progress in his goal of understanding emotions - especially Human emotions - so comparatively late in his experience.

Theory one:

Data did not remember anything about his experiences on Omicron Theta before he was deactivated there.  But it is  possible that he had subconscious memories of the (mostly or all Human) colonists there and his Human creator Doctor Soong, which may have imprinted in his positronic brain a preference for dealing with Humans.

If the crew of the starship *Tripoli* (named after Earth cities) who found Data and reactivated him were mostly or all Human that might have also imprinted Data with an interest in Humans.  *Star Trek Chronology: The History of the Future* says that Data entered Starfleet Academy 3 years after being reactivated and graduated 7 years after being reactivated.

Data's only mentioned Starfleet assignment in the 19 years between graduation and "Encounter at Farpoint" was being on the starship *Trieste* (named after another Earth city) when it passed through an unstable wormhole.

So one possible theory is that Data spent most of the 26 years before "Encounter at Farpoint" in the company of highly nonhuman beings who were either highly unemotional like Vulcans or had strange emotions compared to Humans, despite being somewhat imprinted on Humans and desiring to spend more time among Humans.

In the three years between being reactivated and entering Starfleet academy Data may have examined by mostly highly nonhuman scientists at the Vulcan Science academy or at an Annex of the Daystrom Institute on a world with a highly nonhuman population.

Data may have spent part or all of his time at Starfleet Academy in a campus on Vulcan or some other highly alien world instead of the campus on Earth, or perhaps attended lectures through telepresence without interacting with Human students.

And Data may have spent most of his 19 years in Starfleet before "Encounter at Farpoint" assigned to ships and starbases with nonhuman crews where he would have little opportunity to study Human psychology.  And perhaps Data spent much of his prior Starfleet career on science vessels and research outposts studying strange new worlds and civilizations.

Thus Data may have sought assignment to the Enteprise in large part because its crew  was mostly Human.

Theory 2:

It is possible that Data needed to accumulate a critical mass of observations of Human behavior before he began to understand it, and that he reached the critical mass of observations during the course of TNG.

I hope that some combination of my two theories with the other theories presented here will be enough to sufficiently explain why Data suddenly began to understand Humans much better during the course of STTNG.

Comment: Interesting theories. The first one has little or no support in canon, however.

Comment: Xantec - Yes my first theory has little or no support in canon.   It also has little or no contraction in canon, either, at least up to the point when the second edition of Star Trek Chronology: The History of the Future was published in 1996 and said that almost nothing was known about Data's Starfleet career prior to "Encounter at Farpoint".  And after it was published only the movies First Contact, Insurrection, and Nemesis could have added anything to Data's backstory.  Did any of those three movies say anything about Data's backstory?

Comment: @M.A.Golding - Actually it is contradicted in canon.  In the episode where the crazy scientist lady destroys the Crystalline Entity, Data talks about his time on O T, before the Entity attacked, including playing back her son's log.

Comment: @Xavon_Wrentaile Data had logs and memories from the colonists, but his own memories were wiped.

Comment: @nasch My point was that the original post guesses that he might have had the colonists' memories.  There is no guess or might, that is blatant canon.

Comment: Xavon - dialog from Datalore:  

TASHA: Data, I can't understand how you can hold the memories of four hundred and eleven people. If that means every experience, every day of their life?
DATA: It does not, unfortunately. It means only the knowledge they had accumulated. Actually, I am quite deficient in some basic human information. Sneezing, for example.                                                    
Thus Data did not remember or learn from the human life experiences of the colonists.  And apparently he was not given their social knowledge.